# PHP Monthly Recurrence

Tags: php, fullcalendar, recurrence, rrule

I'm Using [PHP RRule](https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule) for Recurrence in my Project.
Here Daily and Weekly Recurrence are working fine.
I don't know how to use monthly Recurrence in my scenario.

**Monthly scenario:**

> First Sunday of every 2 Months

[image]

**Code:**

```
$dow=array("SU");
$rrule = new RRule([
    'FREQ' => 'MONTHLY',
    'BYMONTHDAY' => 2,  
    'INTERVAL' => 2,
    'BYDAY' => $dow,    
    'DTSTART' => '2016-12-01',
    'UNTIL' => '2017-12-31'
]); 

foreach ( $rrule as $occurrence ) {
    echo "</br>";
    echo $occurrence->format('D Y-m-d');
}

echo $rrule->humanReadable(),"\n";

//OUTPUT
Sun 2017-04-02
every 2 months on Sunday on the 2nd of the month, starting from 12/1/16, until 12/31/17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `BYMONTHDAY`, you need `BYDAY` with a number prefix.

In your situation: `'BYDAY' => '1SU'` means "the first Sunday". `2SU` the second Sunday, `-1SU` the last Sunday etc.

More information:

- https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule/issues/19
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10